# Convert the students marks into respective grades

Tags: sql, oracle

Need a query to print the `ID` and `letter_grade` associated with a student's `max_grade` for each record in the `Student` table. The output must be ordered by ascending ID and should follow the below format :

```
Student 1 has grade: A

Student 2 has grade: C

Student 3 has grade: B

Student 4 has grade: F

But I'm not sure how to pass "id" value into the then clause.

Below is the code I have implemented :

select CASE 
WHEN max_grade < 20 then "Student id has grade: F"
WHEN (max_grade >=20 AND max_grade <40) then "Student id has grade: D"
WHEN (max_grade >=40 AND max_grade <60) then "Student id has grade: C"
WHEN (max_grade >=60 AND max_grade <80) then "Student id has grade: B"
ELSE "Student id has grade: A"
END AS Grade_details from students order by id;
```

Comment: Did you try anything. Check about CASE.

Comment: Hi @Neha. Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please mention the approaches you've tried to solve this? It always helps the responders on the site to know what was tried by the OP. Questions without any such descriptions can often feel like tasks being provided to the contributors.

Comment: Yes, sounds like you want [`case`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/expressions004.htm).

Comment: Now that's interesting. Apparently this was posted by someone going by Neha - but now the poster is @user11719742 and the account is greyed and non-clickable, which may indicate the account has been closed. Are we now seeing the advent of drive-by one-use users who just want a homework question answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to concatenate the id and the letter grade inside the phrase:

```
'Student ? has grade: ?'
```

with this:

```
select 
 'Student ' || id || ' has grade: ' || CASE 
    WHEN max_grade < 20 then 'F' 
    WHEN max_grade < 40 then 'D'
    WHEN max_grade < 60 then 'C'
    WHEN max_grade < 80 then 'B'
    ELSE 'A'
  END AS Grade_details 
FROM students 
ORDER BY id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use case condition in sql query to convert mark to grade

```
CASE
WHEN condition1 THEN result1
WHEN condition2 THEN result2
WHEN conditionN THEN resultN
ELSE result
END;
```

refer this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp) to know about case statement.

```
SELECT studentID, CASE statement FROM table name ORDER BY studentID
```

using order by statement you get output in ascending or descending order

Comment: How do i pass student_id value in the then clause ? I'm only getting like : Student 1 has grade: A and so on..

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use `case` logic:

```
select (case when max_grade < 20 then 'F'
             when max_grade < 40 then 'D'
             when max_grade < 60 then 'C'
             when max_grade < 80 then 'B'
             else 'A'
        end) as letter_grade
```

Note that a `case` expression returns the first matching expression, so only the upper bound is needed.  This version assumes that `max_grade` is not `null`.

Also note that this version assigns a letter grade to students whose max is exactly 80.

Comment: Gordon, I have written the code as below and it's working but I need the "id" column value in the place of "id", how to do i get this. ?                                                    select CASE 
WHEN max_grade < 20 then "Student id has grade: F"
WHEN (max_grade >=20 AND max_grade <40) then "Student id has grade: D"
WHEN (max_grade >=40 AND max_grade <60) then "Student id has grade: C"
WHEN (max_grade >=60 AND max_grade <80) then "Student id has grade: B"
ELSE "Student id has grade: A"
END AS letter_grade from students order by id;

Comment: You don't need the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

We need to set "sql_mode" (For MySql Database)

```
SET sql_mode = 'PIPES_AS_CONCAT';

select 
    CASE
        when max_grade<20 then 'Student '||id||' has grade: F'
        when max_grade>=20 and max_grade<40 then 'Student '||id||'  has grade: D'
        when max_grade>=40 and max_grade<60 then 'Student '||id||'  has grade: C'
        when max_grade>=60 and max_grade<80 then 'Student '||id||' has grade: B'
        when max_grade>=80 then 'Student  '||id||' has grade: A'
    END AS letter_grade
from student order by ID;
```